# Right click selected text on a link, but only copy raw text

Tags: macos, mac, copy-paste, text

I select the text of a hyperlink, but when I right click on it, there's no option to simply copy the text. It only allows to copy the link itself. How can I achieve what I desire?

Comment: I know I can cmd+c, but I want to use the mouse sometimes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click in the space before or after the link and drag across to select the link.

Copy, then paste somewhere and edit out the spaces.

Or double- or triple-click somewhere else on the line to get the whole line or paragraph, copy and edit results.

Or show page source, search for the text, and copy it from there.

Comment: Method one doesnt work very well, method 2 requires editing, and method 3 requires opening the page source. Good idea with the page source though.

Comment: Method one requires editing out the space, as I said.  It usually works for me on Mac.  Not in some IOS apps, though, where tapping far from the link somehow is the same as tapping on it if there is no text between the tap and the link.

Comment: oh. Yes. I forgot.

Comment: "Click in the space before or after the link and drag across to select the link"
ahh just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

*right click, but instead of clicking `copy link`, click `copy`*

---

EDIT:
open automator. Choose `new document`. choose `quick action`. change the top settings to:

[image]

Add a `copy to clipboard` action. Save it.

When you want to copy something, select, then right click it. Select `services`>`whatever you saved that quick action as (eg. "copy")`

This is probably not the most efficient way to do this, but it works

Comment: I don't see that option in most places.

Comment: hmmm. It works on chrome

Comment: try on somewhere outside the browser, like in the Mac Mail app

Comment: I will update my answer